# Kafka ConsumerInterceptor onCommit() method invoked continuously?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using a `KafkaConsumer` with the following settings

- `enable.auto.commit` = `true`
- `auto.commit.interval.ms` = `2000`

.. and polling every 5 seconds. I have a dummy `ConsumerInterceptor` implementation

```
@Override
public void onCommit(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> map) {
    System.out.println("onCommit() invoked with records - " + map.size());
    Set<Map.Entry<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata>> committedEntries = map.entrySet();

    for (Map.Entry<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> committedEntry : committedEntries) {    
        System.out.println("committedRecordTopic " + committedEntry.getKey().topic());
        System.out.println("committedRecordPartition " + committedEntry.getKey().partition());
        System.out.println("committedRecordOffset " + committedEntry.getValue().offset());
    }

}
```

When ever I send a record to Kafka, the interceptor's `onCommit` method is getting invoked repeatedly and I see this kind of output (as per above interceptor) again and again

```
onCommit() invoked with records - 1
committedRecordTopic foo
committedRecordPartition 0
committedRecordOffset 12
```

Why does this happen? If the last record got committed, why is `onCommit()` getting invoked with the same record ? This does not happen when I switch to manual commit with `enable.auto.commit` = `false` and call `commitSync()` in consumer logic

Comment: i don't see how you can say it is the same record

Comment: same topic + same partition + same offset (and same broker of course) = same record. I am just trying this out as a 'hello world' and confused as to why this is happening

Comment: I'm not sure 100% .. this also happen after 2 seconds and you are not getting something like `Kafka Producer error Expiring 10 record(s) for TOPIC:XXXXXX: 6686 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 10 record(s) `?

Comment: not sure we are talking about the same thing @Paizo